# Haml doesn't evaluate embedded Ruby code

Tags: ruby, haml

Why the code below (which is taken from http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_blocks) renders to `<p>See, I can count!</p>` and doesn't output numbers from 42 to 47?

```
- (42...47).each do |i|
  %p= i
%p See, I can count!
```

I used [#haml.try](http://haml-lang.com/try.html) page in order to test the haml snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online version does not allow you to run ruby code, as it says on the website :)

> Give Haml a try online! Just type in some Haml code below, press Render, and see the beautiful HTML output. You can’t use any real Ruby code here, but feel free to use Ruby hash attributes.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you run it locally. The online version may not be evaluating the ruby code.

```
$ haml
- (42...47).each do |i|
  %p= i
%p See, I can count!
^Z
<p>42</p>
<p>43</p>
<p>44</p>
<p>45</p>
<p>46</p>
<p>See, I can count!</p>
```